# VueJS Call to Spring Boot Backend throws SSL error because Port 8081 isn't secured

Tags: vue.js, network-programming, port, plesk

I've currently finished a web app using VueJS/Node frontend with a Spring Boot backend and everythings works fine when I'm testing it over localhost. My frontend runs on port 8080 and my backend over 8081. I've now uploaded everything to my VServer but the calls to the backend don't go through. Everytime I get a ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR in my browsers console.
How the application works in general:
The frontend sends an ID - typed in by the user - to the backend, the backend makes an API-Call to an external system and gets data depending on the ID. Then it sends the data back to the frontend and it gets shown on the website.

I already tried to allow outgoing and incoming traffic on ports 8080 and 8081 (both TCP) with the Plesk Firewall but that didn't change anything. I already read that it could be possible to add a nginx config to forward the calls to 8081 over 456 to get the connection secured but I'm too insecure about nginx and don't want to destroy anything.
The live backend should go over the following domain: matchmaker.wematch-intern.de:8081.

My backend is running over a JAR which I built with Maven, executed on the server with systemctl.

I'm also open to a workaround i.e. over another port or a completely other way to communicate with the backend.